create a Q variable in django orm
I want to actuate this query as one Q variable
In [55]: Practitioner.objects.filter(query).filter(query10).distinct()                                                        
Out[55]: <QuerySet [<Practitioner: Mohsenibod, Hadi>]>

I used this methods but they do not correct:
In [53]: Practitioner.objects.filter(query & query10).distinct()                                                              
Out[53]: <QuerySet []>                                                                    
                                                                                                                              
In [54]: Practitioner.objects.filter(query , query10).distinct()                                                              
Out[54]: <QuerySet []>


If you have questions like this and use a Django orm and want to just translate it into some kind of special queue or raw SQL, or vice-versa, you can use ChatGPT, its free, if you provide it with example data and tell it what you want to do with it, it can generate amazingly accurate results.

You can use Q objects and combine using logical OR operator |, so:
from django.db.models import Q

combined_query = Q(query) | Q(query10)
result = Practitioner.objects.filter(combined_query).distinct()

This constructs a single query by combining the conditions specified in query and query10 using the logical OR operator |. Then, it filters the Practitioner queryset based on this combined query and ensures that the results are distinct.

that is not correct:
In [36]: Practitioner.objects.filter(Q(query) | Q(query10)).distinct()
Out[36]: <QuerySet [<Practitioner: Ahmed, Liban>, <Practitioner: Ahmed, Najma Ayesha>, <Practitioner: Ahmed, Sadaf Khurshid>, <Practitioner: Ahmed, Sara Roxanne>, <Practitioner: Ahmed, Shaheeda Moshfeqa>, <Practitioner: Ahmed, Somaiah>, <Practitioner: Ahn, Eusang>, <Practitioner: Ah-Sue, Sheri Lynn>, <Practitioner: Ailon, Jonathan Isaac>, <Practitioner: Aina, Rima>, <Practitioner: Ainsworth, Craig Douglas>, <Practitioner: Ajisafe, Olaniyi Funso>, < .....

@HosseinSayyedmousavi Would you please provide more information about the queryset?

i solved this problem by a trick in below:

@HosseinSayyedmousavi Gald to see the problem resolved :)

my objects was this:
query = Q(specialties__isnull=False,practices__city__isnull=False,practices__location__latitude__isnull=False,practices__city__id__in=permitted_cities,specialties__in=permitted_specialties)
query10 = Q(practices__city__slug = city)

I do not know what is the problem with django but i solved this error by use kwargs instead of Q objects then write this query:
combined_query = {'specialties__isnull' : False,
'practices__city__isnull' : False,
'practices__location__latitude__isnull' : False,
'practices__city__id__in': permitted_cities,
'specialties__in': permitted_specialties,
'practices__city__slug' : city}

Out[54]: Practitioner.objects.filter(**combined_query).distinct()  
Out[55]: <QuerySet [<Practitioner: Mohsenibod, Hadi>]>

